# Can an Angular 6 Library be bundled and used in an Angular 5 Application?

Tags: angular5, backwards-compatibility, angular6

I'm on a team that is programming a new application and is also developing a pattern library for that application. When we began coding this application, we used Angular 5. However, we have seen it would be much easier to implement the pattern library with Angular 6. If we bundled the Angular 6 library, will it be usable for Angular 5?

Note: The main reason we're using Angular 6 is because it makes producing a pattern library much easier (i.e the new angular CLI). We aren't using any other Angular 6 features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>After some initial testing, I've found that you can. My test was very basic (i.e. one exported component from the library, that only was comprised of divs) but the difference in Angular versions didn't seem to cause errors.</s>

EDIT: ^^ Is incorrect. When I first answered my own question I used a test that ended up being incorrect. I don't think there is a good way to integrate an Angular 6 library into an Angular 5 projects, because the difference in all of the `@angular` dependencies are too great to allow for effective integration. I had to downgrade my library to Angular 5.

Comment: Hi. I'm trying to do the same. How did you achieve this backwards compatibility? Can you edit your answer to add the relevant code?

Comment: @Gus I used the articles [here - part 1](https://blog.angularindepth.com/creating-a-library-in-angular-6-87799552e7e5) and [here - part 2](https://blog.angularindepth.com/creating-a-library-in-angular-6-part-2-6e2bc1e14121)

If you're trying to have the library in the projects folder as angular 6 but your main application as angular 5, that will not work, as angular 5 uses .angular-cli.json and angular 6 uses angular.json. However, you can use npm publish to export your pattern library to a registry and pulling down from that registry wasn't different.

Comment: In this scenario, I have build the angular5 project and create dist folder and in the dist folder there are couples of bundle files and assets folder. After that I have put those folder on some local server so i can access those bundle files using local server. So I want to use those bundle files of my application in another angular 5 project. Do you have any idea how can I integrate it.

Comment: @TejasSavaliya I have edited my answer, sorry about the prior mistake.

Comment: @user3311613 : Do you have any idea to integrate?